# how to set return type of a stored procedure according to a specific table

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, ado.net-entity-data-model

I had made a dynamic stored procedure like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyProcedure]
    @pSelect nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max)

    SET @SQL = 'select ' + @pSelect + ' from tabel1';

    EXEC (@SQL)
END
```

And on updating my entitydatamodel the in context.cs  the above stored procedure is in the form of

```
 virtual int MyProcedure(string pSelect)
            {
                var pSelectParameter = pSelect != null ?
                    new ObjectParameter("pSelect", pSelect) :
                    new ObjectParameter("pSelect", typeof(string));

                return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction("MyProcedure", pSelectParameter);
            }
```

on calling the stored procedure from c# code

```
var result = myDataModel.MyProcedure("Select * From table1").tolist();
```

the above code is showing error because MyProcedure is returning a  integer return type
so how could i set the return type of the stored procedure according to tje select query I am passing to it

HOW DO I MODIFY MY STORED PROCEDURE SO THAT ITS RETURN TYPE IS OF ANY SPECIFIC TABLE TYPE

Comment: Entity Framework has support for native queries: [Entity Framework Raw SQL Queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592907.aspx) - is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: Also, your code results in `"select Select * From table1 from tabel1"`, but I get the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you have to trick the code.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyProcedure]
    @pSelect nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max)

    SET @SQL = 'select ' + @pSelect + ' from tabel1';

    EXEC (@SQL)

   --Remove the below line once you have added the stored procedure to the dbml file.
    select * from table1
END
```

After creating the sp, drag and drop to the c# dbml file. then you can alter the sp by removing the line " select * from table1".

NOTE : if you dont have those columns in the table1, the direct values(any datatype) in the select statement like "select 1 as colmumn1, 'string' as colmumn2, cast('10/01/1900' as datetime) as colmumn3 from table1"

Answer (score 1):

just add @ sign in your parameter.

```
 var pSelectParameter = pSelect != null ?
                new ObjectParameter("@pSelect", pSelect) :
                new ObjectParameter("@pSelect", typeof(string));
```

may be this should work and i believe your are passing only column name in this parameter.